# Pointers to vector returns only last value of vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've got the following code, with a vector of struct HE_face's and an array of struct HE_edge's.  Based on some test I set add a new face to the vector of faces, and set each proceeding edge to the last face added to the vector of faces.  However, for some reason the output is that all the edges are being set to the same final face added to the face vector.
So instead of output:

```
edge: 0 face: 0
edge: 1 face: 0
edge: 2 face: 0
edge: 3 face: 1
edge: 4 face: 1
edge: 5 face: 1
```

I get the output:

```
edge: 0 face: 1
edge: 1 face: 1
edge: 2 face: 1
edge: 3 face: 1
edge: 4 face: 1
edge: 5 face: 1
```

Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
vector<HE_face> f_list ;
int size = 6 ;
HE_edge *edges[size] ;

struct HE_face
{
    HE_face( HE_edge* e, unsigned long i ) : edge(e), normal(NULL), index(i) {}
    HE_face( HE_edge* e, HE_normal* n, unsigned long i ) : edge(e), normal(n), index(i) {}

    unsigned long index ;

    HE_edge* edge ;
    HE_normal* normal ;
} ;

struct HE_edge
{
    HE_edge( HE_vertex* v, HE_edge* p, HE_face* f, HE_edge* n ) : vertex(v), pair(p), face(f), next(n) {}

    HE_edge* next ;
    HE_vertex* vertex ;
    HE_face* face ;
    HE_edge* pair ;
} ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )      // create the edges
{
    if( i%3==0 )
         f_list.push_back( HE_face( edges[i], f_list.size() ) ) ;
    edges[i]->face = &f_list.back() ;       // set the face of the edge
}
for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    cout << "edge: " << i << " face: " << edges[i]->face->index << endl ;
```

Comment: Did you construct the edges? Could you post minimal, complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the address of an element of `f_list`, which address is subsequently invalidated by a `push_back()`.

Quoting my favorite non-official reference:

> This effectively increases the vector size by one, which causes a reallocation of the internal allocated storage if the vector size was equal to the vector capacity before the call. Reallocations invalidate all previously obtained iterators, references and pointers. -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/

Comment: If it was a vector of pointers, that would potentially solve the problem.  Correct?

Comment: Reserve sufficient space initially, store indexes, or use an `std::list`. Or, yes, store pointers in your vectors.  Reallocation won't change the *value* of the entries, only their address.

Comment: Add list does the job without having to change any other code... perfect!  Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 0):

When you say `edges[i]->face = &f_list.back() ;` you store a pointer into the vector internal data, which is only valid until the next call that modifies the vector.  So when you next call `push_back`, these pointers become invalid (dangling) and dereferencing them is undefined.